# Elegant way of stripping the 1st layer of cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a `1x2` cell array a such that

- `a{1, 1}` is a `5x1` int array containing `[1 2 3 4 5]`
- `a{1, 2}` is a `5x1` cell array containing `'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'`

What is the most elegant way of stripping the first layer, producing a `5x2` cell array as follows?

```
1 'aa'
2 'bb'
3 'cc'
4 'dd'
5 'ee'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
% original cell
a = cell(1,2);
a{1} = [1 2 3 4 5];
a{2} = {'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'};

% flattened
aa = reshape([num2cell(a{1}) a{2}], [], 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured one solution out, but am not sure about its "elegantness".

```
a = cell(1, 2);
a{1, 1} = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a{1, 2} = {'aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'};

result = [num2cell(a{1, 1})' a{1, 2}']

result = 

    [1]    'aa'
    [2]    'bb'
    [3]    'cc'
    [4]    'dd'
    [5]    'ee'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
a{1, 1} = [1,2,3,4,5];
a{1, 2} = {'aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'};

temp = num2cell(a{1});
b = {temp{:};a{2}{:}}.'

b = 

    [1]    'aa'
    [2]    'bb'
    [3]    'cc'
    [4]    'dd'
    [5]    'ee'
```

Comment: Error message: `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`

Comment: Hmm, then I fear I have defined `a` wrong. See my edit.

Comment: @FarticlePilter Not really elegant now, but it works.

Comment: Error message: `Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.` This is weird...

Comment: @FarticlePilter Sorry, one more copy/paste error. I should have indeed used copy/paste instead of modifying my original post. `b = {temp{:};a{2}{:}}.'`